# C# for students book exercise 10.2 (Book by Douglas Bell)

Tags: c#

I am reading this book to self teach myself C#. However, I ran across a problem that I just can't figure out a way to tackle.

The question asks me: 
Write a piece of program that remembers the value and compares them as a class. This class has a method NewValue and properties LowestValue and HighestValue.

I understand the question but it asks me to use a track bar which I can't seem to understand how can i store the minimum/maximum value that was previously selected on the trackbar.

My class looks like this:

```
class AmplifierDisplay
{
    private int Low, High;
    public AmplifierDisplay()
    {
        Low = 0;
        High = 0;
    }

    public void NewValue()
    {
      Low = Math.Min(Low, High);
      High = Math.Max(Low, High);
    }

    public int LowestValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Low;
        }
        set
        {
            Low = value;
        }
    }

    public int HighestValue
    {
        get
        {
            return High;
        }
        set
        {
            High = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `NewValue()` method doesn't take in any input. It should be defined as `NewValue(int value)` where you can pass the new value. Otherwise, nothing can't be done here. Unless there is something missing from the provided context.

Comment: I was thinking of passing the value by parameter but then what would be the point of having those properties then? I am pretty sure the question wants me to play with the properties too.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'll need two things:

1) A Comparer implementation to work out the difference between two measurements

2) A Memento pattern implementation to provide a history of the values

Upon each move event, store a memento in some kind of structure such as a List or a Queue. This "NewValue" class looks like a basis for the Memento anyway.

See [Comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not learned about Comparer class yet and the list boxes/arrays are in later chapters of the same book. Isn't there another way of doing it? o.O

Comment: It's Computer Science, you could solve it a million different ways. You just have to try to come up with an efficient and elegant way

Comment: Although the book hasn't taught me about arrays and data structures like stack and queue, I am thinking of using stack array that stores all the values that has been selected so far and try to select each of them using foreach loop and using math.min or math.max to come up with solution. I don't know if this will work as it is my first time trying it aha.. I might just settle with comparer as you have suggested because that does seem to be a very useful class to use in many cases I can think of. Maybe I should start getting used to using that class. Thank you very much bro ^_^

Comment: @SushanLimbu If you are really struggling, ping me a message directly and I will dedicate a little time to helping you.

Comment: Woah :O You are really helpful maan. Thank you very much. I will definitely ping you if I am really struggling although I love to struggle in programming as it forces me to explore and learn more lol ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!! :D

Here is the class code:

class AmplifierDisplay

{

private int Low, High;

public AmplifierDisplay()

{

Low = 0;

High = 0;

}

```
    public void NewValue(int newValue)
    {
      Low = Math.Min(Low, newValue);
      High = Math.Max(High, newValue);
    }

    public int LowestValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Low;
        }
        set
        {
            Low = value;
        }
    }

    public int HighestValue
    {
        get
        {
            return High;
        }
        set
        {
            High = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in the main program:

AmplifierDisplay amplify = new AmplifierDisplay();

private int newValue;

```
    public Chapter10Ex2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        amplify.HighestValue = 0;           
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        newValue = trackBar1.Value;                   
    }       

    private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {          
        amplify.NewValue(newValue);
        lblMinMax.Text = amplify.LowestValue.ToString() + " , " + amplify.HighestValue.ToString();
    }
```